# Github email questions

Tags: git, github

I am running Fedora 20 which gives me the option to set up Evolution. I do not want to but I still want github to put my real email address on my commits. How do I do this, or will github do this once I set up my account? At the moment, without an account setup, it is defaulting to name@localhost.localdomain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I do not want to but I still want github to put my real email address on my commits.

The email address is picked up with a git setting and is unrelated to whether or not Evolution is setup.

Run

```
git config --global user.email "username@example.com"
```

to for git to attribute your commits to a specific email for all repos. If you want only a single repo to be affected, cd to the repo and run

```
git config user.email "username@example.com"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. This only needs to be ran once, right? It'll apply to all my projects, all commits...

Comment: yes, that's right - updated the answer.